# what are DocumentElement's children?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a simple XML file as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myConfig>
  <datasets>                        
      <dataset name="set1">                 
        <var name="orgName">org1</var>              
      </dataset>                    
    </datasets>         
</myConfig>
```

When I print the size of the DocumentElement's children it shows me 3. I was expecting only one: <datasets>.
Which are the other two children of DocumentElement?

Thanks in advance 
--Vaman

Comment: You should accept the other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the other two children are dataset and var.  In other words - the count is recursive.  So you have A -> B -> C -> D :  D, C, are both children of A as well as B.

One way to confirm this: write a for loop that goes through each child and prints out the element name.

This is probably specific to the xml parser though.  If you called a similar method with a different xml parser, there is a good chance you could get a different number. Some might return 1, some might return 4 (one for the text node containing "org1").

Answer (score 6):

A text node containing `\n` and the indent, `<dataset>` element, another text node. **Update** the last text node contains `\n` only.

Comment: @org.life.java Pardon? whitespace text becomes a child (text node) of the element node that contains it.

Comment: Thanks All for the prompt explanations.